# Removing all HTML tags using BeautifulSoup4 (python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to tackle this for a while but the only way I managed to do this is by using a complex while loop.

I want to input the following:

```
"<td colspan='2' class='ToEx'>This is a test (<i> to see </i> this works) and I really hope it does</td>"
```

and output this:

```
"This is a test (to see if this works) and I really hope it does"
```

In essence, I want to *remove* everything with "< >" and whatever is in between. The best I can do with a few commands is:

```
"This is a test (<i> to see </i> this works) and I really hope it does"
```

But then I'm left with these annoying guys: `<i></i>`

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = "<td colspan='2' class='ToEx'>This is a test (<i> to see </i> this works) and I really hope it does</td>" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
content = soup.find_all("td","ToEx")
content[0].renderContents()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print the `.text` attribute of the tag, it gives you its text

```
print(content[0].text)
```

Output:

```
This is a test ( to see  this works) and I really hope it does
```

Comment: first thing I tried, something else seems to be going on because I'm getting an error. I'll look into it a bit more, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would use `get_text()` - it has been designed for this sort of situation:

```
text = "<td colspan='2' class='ToEx'>This is a test (<i> to see </i> this works) and I really hope it does</td>" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
print(soup.get_text())
```

This should work [as per the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

I have never seen `.text` used before, instead, in Beautiful Soup 4, use `.string` - if you want to use that do:

```
text="<td colspan='2' class='ToEx'>This is a test (<i> to see </i> this works) and I really hope it does</td>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

for string in soup.strings:
     print(str(string),end="")
```

Both will output:

> This is a test ( to see  this works) and I really hope it does

Both will work equally well, but `get_text()` will be easier to use, especially if you want to save the text to a variable etc.